# drupal 7 captcha image doesnt change

Tags: drupal-7, captcha

I have installed the captcha module into my drupal 7 website and have it displaying on two forms. It is working properly other than it is caching the captcha so it is the same when I do a refresh. If I go into the admin and turn off the cache they are still the same but if I go and hit the clear all caches button it changes to a new one the next time I go to the page.
Anyone have any ideas? Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple following 3 steps and you get out from your error.

1. uninstall captcha module.
2. clear catch history
3. go to module page and enable captcha module.

it will work for you.